# UIViewTable not updating NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am devloping an application "view based" and I used Table View in it

I was able to view all the strings in the table but not any variable

```
- (void)updateView{
    [listData dealloc];
    listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *testString = forecast.routeNo;
    [listData addObject:@"first"];
    [listData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", testString]];
    NSLog(@"this is the forecast routeNo = %@", testString);
}
```

the value of the string instially null but it is changing which i can see it debugger, but not in the table

so i can see the correct value in the debugger but when ever it is updated with the new value it doesn't update in the table view

so my question is it enough to change the values in the array or should i call some method or is it something else

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow what you're saying, but I think what you're doing is updating the UITableView's data source, but not telling it that the data has changed.

As such, if you simply call your [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `reloadData` method, the table should update with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delegate the tableView to the self